# C - Error is "free(): invalid next size (normal) "

Tags: pointers, gdb, valgrind, sigabrt

I just can not find what is causing this problem.

```
MYSQL *startup(unsigned char *path_to_file, int size_of_path) {
MYSQL *con;
bool path_is_file = false;
bool path_is_directory = false;
FILE *startup_file;
int i;
unsigned char buffer[LINEBUFFERSIZE];
unsigned char string[LINEBUFFERSIZE];
unsigned char c;

//Allocate memory for the new file path
unsigned char *path;
path = (unsigned char *) malloc(size_of_path);
if(path == NULL)
    error("Could not allocate memory for path to file.\nIn startup()\n");

//Check if startup file exists or if it is a directory
//Bug is somewehre here!!!!
struct stat s;
printf("%s", path_to_file);
if(stat(path_to_file, &s) == 0) {
    if(s.st_mode & S_IFDIR) {
        //It's a directory
        path_is_directory = true;
        //Add the standard startup file name to the directory
        path = (unsigned char *) realloc(path, size_of_path + sizeof(STARTUP_FILE));
        if(path == NULL)
            error("Could not reallocate memory for variable path.\nIn startup()\n");
        //Put the strings together
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", path_to_file, STARTUP_FILE);
    }
    else if(s.st_mode & S_IFREG) {
        //It's a file
        path_is_file = true;
        path = path_to_file;
    }//End else if
    else //Someting else. abort
        error("Given file is neither file or directory.\nIn startup()\n");
}
else //Error
    error("Error in looking up type of path.\nIn startup()\n");;


//Check if the startup file exists
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", path);
if((startup_file = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
    //File does not exist, create a basics one for the user to modify
    if((startup_file = fopen(path, "w+")) == NULL)
        error("Could not create the startup file.\n");
    //Write the standard text to the new file, so the user can modify it
    //sizeof(STARTUP_FILE_TEXT)-1 as gedit cries if there is a terminator at the end
    fwrite(STARTUP_FILE_TEXT, sizeof(STARTUP_FILE_TEXT[0]), sizeof(STARTUP_FILE_TEXT)-1, startup_file);
}//End outer if


//Read from the startup file and find out which tables and database are needed and may have to be created
//While loop will run although if file was just created, fix it
section current;
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), startup_file) != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(buffer, "[DATABASES]")) {
        //Every line now should contain the name of dbs, until new section
        current = DATABASES;
    }
    else if(strcmp(buffer, "[TABLES]")) {
        //Every line now should contain the name of dbs, until new section
        current = TABLES;
    }
    else {
        //Read the lines and create the table or database
        //Ignore everything behind #
        //Just numbers and letters are allowed
        //Read one line and save it into buffer
        //What happens, if the line exceeds buffer length and is split into to?
        //Process every character, but do not exceed the buffers limit (also save one for the '\0' termiantor)
        for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(buffer)-1); i++) {
            //Allowed characters are: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dash, underscore and space
            //Read until '\n' or '#' or if not allowed characters are used print error and do not use it
            c = buffer[i];
            if(isalnum(c) || (c == '-') || (c == '_') || (c == ' '))  {
                //Correct
                string[i] = c;
            }//End if
            else if(c == '\n' || c == '\0') {
                //End of line or end of string, not checking for EOF as fgets already does it \
                and it would requried the int data type
                break;
            }//End else if
            else {
                //Wrong, stop
                printf("Wrong character used in setup file.\nWrong characters was: %c\n", c);
                break;
            }//End else
        }//End for
        //Add terminator at the end
        string[i] = '\0';
        //Create table or database
        switch(current) {
            case DATABASES:
                create_db(string, sizeof(string));
                break;
            case TABLES:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }//End switch

    }
}//End while

//Create db and then open the database as a specific user
//create_db();
con = open_db("user1", "passwd", "Vocables");

//Clean up
fclose(startup_file);
free(path);
return con;
}
```

Running in gdb I get:

```
    (gdb) run 8080 ~/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/
Starting program: /home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server 8080 ~/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server//startup.txt
*** Error in `/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000000603030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7198e)[0x7ffff6b0f98e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x76dee)[0x7ffff6b14dee]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x775cb)[0x7ffff6b155cb]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6893d)[0x7ffff6b0693d]
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server[0x4016b8]
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server[0x4012bc]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ffff6abe800]
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server[0x401089]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 00:24 261912                             /home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:24 261912                             /home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/bin/Debug/Porifera-Server
00603000-00624000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff5f8a000-7ffff5fa2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180623                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so
7ffff5fa2000-7ffff61a1000 ---p 00018000 08:03 1180623                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so
7ffff61a1000-7ffff61a2000 r--p 00017000 08:03 1180623                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so
7ffff61a2000-7ffff61a3000 rw-p 00018000 08:03 1180623                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so
7ffff61a3000-7ffff61a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff61a7000-7ffff61a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180634                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.21.so
7ffff61a9000-7ffff63a9000 ---p 00002000 08:03 1180634                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.21.so
7ffff63a9000-7ffff63aa000 r--p 00002000 08:03 1180634                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.21.so
7ffff63aa000-7ffff63ab000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 1180634                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.21.so
7ffff63ab000-7ffff65f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1226972                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7ffff65f8000-7ffff67f7000 ---p 0024d000 08:03 1226972                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7ffff67f7000-7ffff6815000 r--p 0024c000 08:03 1226972                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7ffff6815000-7ffff6821000 rw-p 0026a000 08:03 1226972                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7ffff6821000-7ffff6825000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff6825000-7ffff6893000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1226971                    /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7ffff6893000-7ffff6a92000 ---p 0006e000 08:03 1226971                    /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7ffff6a92000-7ffff6a97000 r--p 0006d000 08:03 1226971                    /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7ffff6a97000-7ffff6a9e000 rw-p 00072000 08:03 1226971                    /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7ffff6a9e000-7ffff6c37000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180590                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7ffff6c37000-7ffff6e37000 ---p 00199000 08:03 1180590                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7ffff6e37000-7ffff6e3b000 r--p 00199000 08:03 1180590                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7ffff6e3b000-7ffff6e3d000 rw-p 0019d000 08:03 1180590                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7ffff6e3d000-7ffff6e41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff6e41000-7ffff6e57000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180909                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff6e57000-7ffff7056000 ---p 00016000 08:03 1180909                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7056000-7ffff7057000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 1180909                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7057000-7ffff715a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180659                    /usr/lib/libm-2.21.so
7ffff715a000-7ffff735a000 ---p 00103000 08:03 1180659                    /usr/lib/libm-2.21.so
7ffff735a000-7ffff735b000 r--p 00103000 08:03 1180659                    /usr/lib/libm-2.21.so
7ffff735b000-7ffff735c000 rw-p 00104000 08:03 1180659                    /usr/lib/libm-2.21.so
7ffff735c000-7ffff744c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180915                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
7ffff744c000-7ffff764c000 ---p 000f0000 08:03 1180915                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
7ffff764c000-7ffff7654000 r--p 000f0000 08:03 1180915                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
7ffff7654000-7ffff7656000 rw-p 000f8000 08:03 1180915                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
7ffff7656000-7ffff766b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff766b000-7ffff7680000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1183894                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7ffff7680000-7ffff787f000 ---p 00015000 08:03 1183894                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7ffff787f000-7ffff7880000 r--p 00014000 08:03 1183894                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7ffff7880000-7ffff7881000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 1183894                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7ffff7881000-7ffff7b67000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1223645                    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7ffff7b67000-7ffff7d67000 ---p 002e6000 08:03 1223645                    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7ffff7d67000-7ffff7d6e000 r--p 002e6000 08:03 1223645                    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7ffff7d6e000-7ffff7dd2000 rw-p 002ed000 08:03 1223645                    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7ffff7dd2000-7ffff7ddb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ddb000-7ffff7dfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1180654                    /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7ffff7fc3000-7ffff7fcb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff6000-7ffff7ff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff8000-7ffff7ffa000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00021000 08:03 1180654                    /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00022000 08:03 1180654                    /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6ad14b7 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

When executing single lines in gdb you get short before the error occurs:

```
    26              path_is_directory = true;
(gdb) n
28              path = (unsigned char *) realloc(path, size_of_path + sizeof(STARTUP_FILE));
(gdb) n
29              if(path == NULL)
(gdb) n
32              sprintf(path, "%s/%s", path_to_file, STARTUP_FILE);
(gdb) n
51      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", path);
(gdb) n
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server//startup.txt
52      if((startup_file = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
(gdb) n
```

When I execute the next line after line 52 the problem occurs.

Using 'valgrind --leak-check=yes ./Porifera-Server 8080 ~/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server' it actually runs correctly. But with a blameful list of "errors":

```
    [linux@linux Debug]$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./Porifera-Server 8080 ~/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server
==17917== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17917== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17917== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17917== Command: ./Porifera-Server 8080 /home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53E04: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c8709e is 14 bytes inside a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53E08: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870a6 is 2 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53E0C: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870ae is 10 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 1
==17917==    at 0x5E53D3E: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870b6 is 18 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 4
==17917==    at 0x5E53D60: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870b7 is 19 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 1
==17917==    at 0x5E44B8D: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E17F1D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870bb is 23 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 1
==17917==    at 0x5E44B8D: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870bc is 12 bytes after a block of size 32 in arena "client"
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid write of size 1
==17917==    at 0x5E3AC39: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870c7 is 23 bytes after a block of size 32 in arena "client"
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 1
==17917==    at 0x5E18CA2: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53DF9: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870a0 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53DFD: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870a8 is 4 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 1
==17917==    at 0x5E53D3B: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870b0 is 12 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 2
==17917==    at 0x5E53D4B: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870b1 is 13 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 4
==17917==    at 0x5E53D5E: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870b3 is 15 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53D90: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870b7 is 19 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== Invalid read of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53D93: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E19960: buffered_vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E145D4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F096: fprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016A6: startup (server_func.c:51)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870bf is 15 bytes after a block of size 32 in arena "client"
==17917== 
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server/startup.txt
==17917== Syscall param open(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==17917==    at 0x5EAB2E0: __open_nocancel (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E43524: _IO_file_open (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E4366F: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E38913: __fopen_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x4016B7: startup (server_func.c:52)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c870a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
/home/linux/Cloud/Decrypted/Porifera-Server
IPv4 TCP Server started...
Incoming connection from client having IPv4 address: 127.0.0.1
Message from client: Hello
Value is: 4
==17917== 
==17917== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17917==     in use at exit: 65,928 bytes in 19 blocks
==17917==   total heap usage: 77 allocs, 58 frees, 124,873 bytes allocated
==17917== 
==17917== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 7
==17917==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x4E98839: my_malloc (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E94B63: ??? (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E57244: mysql_server_init (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E5DC76: mysql_init (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x401B0B: open_db (vocable_trainer.c:48)
==17917==    by 0x401858: startup (server_func.c:118)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== 160 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 7
==17917==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x4E98839: my_malloc (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E93D49: ??? (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E69A9D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E5724B: mysql_server_init (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x4E5DC76: mysql_init (in /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17917==    by 0x401B0B: open_db (vocable_trainer.c:48)
==17917==    by 0x401858: startup (server_func.c:118)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917== 
==17917== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17917==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17917==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17917==      possibly lost: 192 bytes in 2 blocks
==17917==    still reachable: 65,736 bytes in 17 blocks
==17917==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17917== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==17917== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==17917== 
==17917== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17917== ERROR SUMMARY: 64 errors from 19 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I just can't find it; other people with a similar error had either an '\n' in the path to the file for the `fopen` function or had not initialised a ptr but tried to free it. I have not touched any ptr-free function since last time it worked and I have currently not found a ptr that is causing this problem.

Comment: It says that the buffer you create with realloc() is too small, so the following `sprintf(path, "%s/%s", path_to_file, STARTUP_FILE);` likely thrashes memory. However, we don't know what sizeof(STARTUP_FILE) or size_of_path  is or if those are actually correct -  perhaps STARTUP_FILE is a char* but you're assuming it's an array. . Though, you need to allocate room for the "/" and the nul terminator as well.

Comment: Yep, you're right, altough I was sure that it was enough memory allocated. But that solves the problem. Could you please tell me how you found out, or quotethe line of the gdb or valgrind output so I know next time, as I am still a beginner. :-)

Comment: I used sizeof(argv[2]), but it returns me the absolutly wrong length. Is there a way to find out the size of a command line argument?

Comment: Yes, strlen(argv[2]) gives you the length, not including the nul terminator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you encounter errors, start with the 1. one , it might be the cause of the following errors.

```
==17917== Invalid write of size 8
==17917==    at 0x5E53E04: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E44BDD: _IO_default_xsputn (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E18C61: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E3AC2A: vsprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x5E1F266: sprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==17917==    by 0x401647: startup (server_func.c:32)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
==17917==  Address 0x6c8709e is 14 bytes inside a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x40160B: startup (server_func.c:28)
==17917==    by 0x4012BB: main (server.c:23)
```

In this stack trace, the interresting pieces is the code of your program, as we can assume the code in the runtime/standard library to work.

Valgrind tells you 2 things here:

1. You're accessing memory you're not supposed to (Invalid write of size 8), in the startup function in the file server_func.c at line 32
2. The memory you're accessing is 14 bytes past a buffer of 20 bytes that you allocated at server_func.c line 28

Line 28:  `path = (unsigned char *) realloc(path, size_of_path + sizeof(STARTUP_FILE));`

Line 32: `sprintf(path, "%s/%s", path_to_file, STARTUP_FILE);`

So on line 28 you don't allocate room for the "/" separator, and possibly not the nul terminator.

You also need to ensure `size_of_path` is correct, and that `sizeof(STARTUP_FILE)` gives you the correct size, which it will if `STARTUP_FILE` is a char array, but it'll be wrong if it's a char pointer. Perhaps you need to use `strlen(STARTUP_FILE)`

Assuming `size_of_path` is correct, you might need to calculate the buffer size as `size_of_path + strlen(STARTUP_FILE) + 2`

Comment: H, thanks for explaining :-) size_of_path was incorrect as I used sizeof(argv[2]) to find it out, but it is a char pointer, so I changed it to strlen(argv[2]). :-)